# ASCII to Hexadecimal - ASM

Tags: assembly, hex, ascii

Checked around and didn't see any already answered questions that help. So I know to take the ASCII character of '9' you can subtract 30h to get the hexadecimal value of 9h.

Now to get the hexidecimal value of the ASCII character of 'A', would you have to subtract 32h and then add 1d? Am I at all on the right track?

Comment: Look up one of the many ASCII tables on the internet, and you'll see how this is arranged.

Comment: I have I think I'm just confused as to what parts count when subtracting the hexidecimal value for example the 2E or the 3A. Logically I am thinking that the A-F hexidecimal count though, so in that case I would just subtract 37h.

Comment: Letters are not contiguous with decimal digits. A single subtraction won't do the job to produce hex values for all the hex characters.

Answer (score 0):

When getting a number from its ASCII value, you can subtract `0x30`

```
sub al, 0x30
```

... or simply and by `0x0F`, if you're sure it's a number

```
and al, 0x0F
```

When getting a character from its ASCII value, you must refer to the ASCII intervals.

```
sub al, 0x41 ; for upper-case characters (0x41 - 0x5A)
sub al, 0x61 ; for lower-case characters (0x61 - 0x7A)
```